# Web scraping using php

Tags: php, web-crawler

M trying to crawl some data from a URL 
with the help of simple html dom.
But when id start my crawler its giving an error

** failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found**

i have tried cUrl but 404 error is thrown.

here my php simple dom code

```
function getURLContent($url)
{
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($url);
    /* i perfome some opetions here*/
}
```

and with cUrl

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
echo $data; 
curl_close($curl);
```

How could i do this..?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you sure you're using the right URL?

Comment: You're either not using the right URL or the remote site is rejecting your requests because you've been detected as crawler.

Comment: fake a browser by sending correct headers, check this SO [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926876/can-a-curl-based-http-request-imitate-a-browser-based-request-completely) to give you an idea

Comment: yeah m using the correct url...even i print the url on the browser...when i copy paste the url in browser, it works totally fine..

Comment: [Debugging PHP `cURL`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757071/php-debugging-curl)

Comment: What URL are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Yes try to configure the useragent

```
 curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
```

Answer (score 0):

add these to your code and try

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; rv:1.7.3) Gecko/20041001 Firefox/0.10.1");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers); //set headers
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // set true for https urls
```

Answer (score 0):

404 Error is obvious, page not found. Try [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) for catching the parameters needed as your physical browser catches, and pass the same parameters via cURL in your script.

If you are getting Blocked error page, means try changing User-Agent OR use a [proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5211887/how-to-use-curl-via-a-proxy) address(you can easily get free proxy on internet) OR try to maintaining the session while requesting your page, Fiddler will help you in this.